# How to make a python function as callback of a c++ function

Tags: c++, python, boost-python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass callback from python to c++ using boost::python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204664/pass-callback-from-python-to-c-using-boostpython)

I have to make a python function as callback of a c++ function.How to do?Where can I find some examples??
I want to use boost.python.

Comment: Does that mean you want to call a python function from a C++ function?

Comment: you make a c++ function as callback of a c++ function and call the python function inside it

Comment: @David Robinson: the poster explicitely asked for a boost-python solution, so I think this is a valid question.

Comment: @cideous: which poster? Both this question and the original ask explicitly for boost::python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach to this (not the only way)

In C++ I have a class that provides a callback in the following way:

```
struct Mesh {
 template<class Visitor>
  void visitChildren(Visitor& v)
  {
     [...]
     v.visit([...])
  }
}
```

and then when I export the class to python (still C++)

```
struct ChildrenVisitor 
{
   ChildrenVisitor(PyObject* self)
        : self(self) 
   {}

  void visit( /* .... */ )
  {
    call_method<void>(self, "visit" /*, [...] */ );
  }

 private:
    PyObject* self; // 1
};
```

The export of the visitor itself to python

```
typedef ChildrenVisitor ClassT;
class_<ClassT, boost::noncopyable >("ChildrenVisitor",
    init<PyObject*>() );
```

And for the export of `Mesh` you do

```
.def("visitChildren", &Mesh::template visitChildren<ChildrenVisitor> )
```

I always used `...` where you can insert any of your arguments.

In python you do something like this

```
class MyVisitor(ChildrenVisitor): 
  def __init__(self):
    ChildrenVisitor.__init__(self,self)

  def visit(self):
    # do whatever you want
```

I also like to make a subclass of `ChildrenVisitor` that accepts lambda functions, that makes writing visitors in python single lines.

---

Oh, btw. if you want to call the function at some later point then you would need to change the C++ implementation to something like this

```
struct ChildrenVisitorBase 
{
  virtual void visit( /* .... */ ) = 0;
};

struct Mesh {
  void registerCallback(shared_ptr<ChildrenVisitorBase> v)
  {
     visitors.push_back(v)
  }

  void doSomeWork() {
    // ...
    for(int i=0; i < visitors.size(); ++i)
      visitors[i]->visit( /* ... */ )
  }

  std::vector<  shared_ptr<ChildrenVisitorBase> > visitors;
}
```

And make `ChildrenVisitor` implement `ChildrenVisitorBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered by [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65210-implementing-c-function-callbacks-using-python/).

If the function you want to have as a callback is already kown at compile time, you should use `PyEval_CallObject(...);`. If the function must be defined at runtime, use the scheme shown in the recipe to receive the functor pointer.